# Assignment within a ternary operator, an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, ternary-operator

I have a colleague who uses ternary operators this way (In javascript):

```
var genderLabel = '';
isMale? genderLabel  = 'Man' : genderLabel  = 'Woman';
```

In C#, I'd just do that .

```
var genderLabel = isMale? "Man" : "Woman";
```

My colleague says it's a javascript coding convention... is that true? I'm no javascript expert and I dislike that language... When I review code, I focus on my left hand-side to follow a variable initialization or assignment, that kind of style forces me to read the whole line.

I'm also maintaining a Java code of an ex-employee, he uses ternary operators the same way. Is that an anti-pattern? I think it should be disallowed by the compiler the same way it's disallowed in a if statement :

```
if(x = 2)
{
   ...
}
```

This won't compile in C#.

Comment: Never have I ever seen that before. Not only is a big no-no as it takes up a lot more space from repetition, it's cluttered and semantically weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My colleague says it's a javascript coding convention... is that true?

No.

> Is that an anti-pattern?

Usually a line by itself is a statement, however this

```
isMale ? genderLabel = 'Man' : genderLabel = 'Woman';
```

is an expression, with a side effect of setting the value of `genderLabel`. Is that a good practice? I don't know, however if you think that is a good practice, then you will also have to allow this:

```
var a = 1, b = 2;
b = [a][a = b, 0];    # swap a and b
```

Your colleague might as well do:

```
if(isMale) genderLabel = 'Man';
else       genderLabel = 'Woman';
```

which is much clearer.